# Create a folder on android A3 2016 6.0.1 marshmallow

Tags: home-screen-folders

I want to create a folder on my samsung A3
When i search the web i find 2 things

1. Press the edit button on the right top of the screen and then drag amd drop an app on top of an other to create a folder.

   Not working . When pressing the edit button the only thing i can do is remove the apps or add new apps .all the apps have a minus sign on them .
2. Press and hold on an app and then choose "create folder" choice that appears after holding the app.

Not working . When press and hold on the app nothing happens.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on my S7 Edge:

1. Open the App Drawer.
2. Press *Edit* in upper-right corner.
3. Press and hold an app, then drag it on top of another app to create a folder.